# Docker-compose : unable to connect to mysql from rails app first time , next run it works

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am creating developer environment for rails app using docker, docker-compose and docker-sync. When I run docker-compose up first time it builds the image of my rails app and downloads mysql image, but not able to connect it, but if I quit this and run docker-compose up again everything works fine. Here are my docker configurations

```
Dockerfile:
FROM ruby:2.5.1

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
  build-essential \ 
  nodejs \
  vim \
  mysql-client \
  apt-transport-https \
  build-essential

RUN curl -s -N https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -\
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn 

RUN mkdir /rails-app
ENV RAILS_HOME /rails-app


WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

WORKDIR /rails-app
ADD . /rails-app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bash"]
```

Below is my docker-compose

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    web:
      image: "rails_app"
      build: .
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      env_file:
        - web_env
        - db_env
      depends_on:
        - db
      command: >
          bash -c "bundle exec rails db:schema:load &&
                   bundle exec rails db:seed &&
                   rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid &&
                   bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    db:
      image: library/mysql:5.6.42
      env_file:
        - db_env
```

docker-compose dev file for volume syncing

```
docker-compose-dev.yml
version: '3'
services:
      web:
         volumes:
            - rails_app_volume_sync:/rails-app:nocopy

volumes:
   rails_app_volume_sync:
      external: true
```

docker-sync file

```
docker-sync.yml
version: "2"
syncs:
    rails_app_volume_sync:
       src: '.'
       sync_host_ip: 'auto'
       sync_strategy: 'unison'
       notify_terminal: true
```

environment files:

```
web_env:
DATABASE_HOST=db
RAILS_ENV=development

db_env:
MYSQL_DATABASE=development_exp
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=dev
MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
```

and my database config is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['MYSQL_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
```

when I run docker-sync-stack start I get the following error after the images are build.

```
web_1  | Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (111 "Connection refused")
```

if I stop the containers and run it again, its working, why is it failing first time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't waiting for the database to be ready before running the migrations. `depends_on` only guarantee that your mysql process in the container is started but it has no way to know when the mysql process has initialized and available to process new connections.

A solution can be to wait for the TCP port to be up, some use [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) for it. Another solution is to simply fail and restart the container until the database is ready (set the Restart Policy of the container to always).

Comment: Thanks you, I used on-failure: restart option and that worked, the issue as you said before  db gets created, rails was trying to connect to it.